# vba get the average daily score for multiple responses per day

Tags: vba, excel

I have data that looks like this:

```
date        v1  v2  v3  v4
1/16/2015   5   5   5   5
1/22/2015   5   2   5   5
1/22/2015   5   2   5   5
1/23/2015   5   5   5   5
1/23/2015   5   5   5   5
1/23/2015   5   5   5   5
1/24/2015   5   5   5   5
1/24/2015   5   5   5   5
1/25/2015   5   4   5   5
```

I need to output the average scores for each value (v1, v2, v3, v4) for each day. I have output a unique list of dates in another worksheet like this:

```
date        avg val 1   avg val 2   avg val 3   avg val 4
1/16/2015                   
1/22/2015                   
1/23/2015               
1/24/2015
1/25/2015
```

how can i iterate through all values of v1 for each unique date, average them, and then enter that number into the average column for its matching date?

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a formula to use for this usually works better when the the header labels match so you do not have to hard code the cross-referenced criteria in.

[image: AVERAGEIF in 2 directions]

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX($B$2:$E$10, , MATCH(H$1, $B$1:$E$1, 0)), $A$2:$A$10, $G2)
```

With the revised header labels (as per image) that can be filled both right and down. If you want to retain your sample header labels (different from data table), you will have to hard-code the *V1*, *V2*, etc into the `MATCH` function.

The formula uses `INDEX` and `MATCH` to provide the column and `AVERAGEIFS` takes care of the date criteria. `AVERAGEIF` could be used but the syntax is slightly different.